# SQLalchemy not convert None to string

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following simplified model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Example(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'example'

        source = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
```

When I do the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?charset=utf8".format(
        'user', 'password', 'localhost', 'db'),
    encoding='utf8',   echo=False)
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
source = None
session.add(Example(source=source))
```

The mysql table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `source` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It inserts into mysql the value of 'None' as source.

But what I want is to try to import a NULL value and throw a mysql exception.

Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve] that one can copy&paste and observe the erronous behaviour. In other words using your (incomplete) model and the example code MySQL does raise an error.

Comment: I improved the question with the imports and the mysql schema definition

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Integrity error raised as expected.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce. Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using sqlalchemy 1.1.13

Comment: I'm inclined to think that your example code here might not match your actual code and you've at some point taken the string representation of `None` instead of the actual value.